# how to get value on first click?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been stuck in this part of the project for a couple of days now, even after a lot of research I still couldn't solve it, so I need to get a variable that is in the contextAPI, but it only updates to the value I need on the second click, but it's not this, I need it on the first click

AuthContext.ts

```
import React, { createContext, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { api } from "../services/api"
import { setCookie } from 'nookies'
import Router from 'next/router';


type User = {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  avatar_url?: string;
  cpf: string;
  password: string;
}

type Empresas = {
  CODIGO: number;
  RAZAO: string;
}


type SignInCredentials = {
  cpf: string;
  password: string;
  empresa?: number;
}


type AuthContextType = {
  signIn(data: SignInCredentials): Promise<void>;
  user: User;
  empresas: Empresas[];
  count: number;
}
type ResponseProps = {
  data: {
    payload: Empresas[];
  };
}
type ResponseUserProps = {
  data: {
    payload: {
      token: string;
    }
  }
}


export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType)

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number | undefined>()
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [empresas, setEmpresas] = useState<Empresas[]>([]);

  async function signIn({ cpf, password, empresa }: SignInCredentials) {
    setUser({
      cpf: cpf,
      password: cpf
    })

    if (!empresa) {
      const response: ResponseProps = await api.post('/session', {
        LOGIN: cpf,
        SENHA: password
      })
      const empresas = response.data.payload;
      setEmpresas(empresas);
      setCount(empresas.length)

    }

    if (empresa) {
      const response: ResponseUserProps = await api.post('/session', {
        LOGIN: cpf,
        SENHA: password,
        EMPRESA: empresa
      })
      console.log(response.data)
      const { token } = response.data.payload;

      setCookie(undefined, '@allNube.token', token, {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hour
      })
      api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;

      Router.push('/dashboard')
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signIn, user, empresas, count }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and here I need to update the updated value which in this specific case has to be two

```
export function Login() {
  const { empresas, count } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log(count);
        if (count > 1) {
          onSelectCompanyDrawer();
        }
        Router.push("/dashboard");
      }}
      w="200px"
      h="48px"
      mb="4"
      type="submit"
    >
      Acessar
    </Button>
  );
}
```

some light?

Comment: What i understand, your count is not defined when it comes. It will push to `dashboard` route first

Comment: where do you call `signIn` function? It should be called before you click on your Acessar button

Comment: set inital value of count to 0

Comment: I call signIn on the Login page

Comment: I already tried to set it to zero too

Answer (score 0):

```
export function Login() {
  const { empresas, count } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [cpf, setCpf] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const { onOpen, isOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
  const { onOpen: onForgetModal, isOpen: isForgetModal, onClose: onCloseForgetModal } = useDisclosure();
  const { onOpen: onForgetDrawer, isOpen: isForgetDrawer, onClose: onCloseForgetDrawer } = useDisclosure();
  const { onOpen: onSelectCompanyDrawer, isOpen: isSelectCompanyDrawer, onClose: onCloseSelectCompanyDrawer } = useDisclosure();
  const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isLargerThan720] = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 720px)")
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
  const { control, handleSubmit: handleCompany } = useForm()



  async function handleSignIn({ cpf, password, }: dataProps) {
    const cpfFormatted = (cpf.replace(/\D+/g, '')).toString();
    const data = {
      cpf: cpfFormatted,
      password,
    }
    setCpf(cpfFormatted);
    setPassword(password);
    signIn(data);
  }

  async function handleSelectCompany({ company }: companyProps) {
    let companyInt = Number(company)

    const data = {
      cpf: cpf,
      password: password,
      empresa: companyInt
    }
    console.log(data)
    signIn(data);
  }

return (
  <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    console.log(count)
                    if (count > 1) {
                      onSelectCompanyDrawer();
                    }
                    Router.push('/dashboard')
                  }}
                  w="200px"
                  h="48px"
                  mb="4"
                  type="submit"
                >Acessar</Button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if someone goes through something similar, my solution is down

```
     useEffect(() => {
    console.log(empresas.length)
    if (empresas.length > 1) {
      onSelectCompanyDrawer()
    }
  }, [empresas])
```

on the login page I did a useEffect and an if to open the modal, and not on the button anymore, as it was before